# Sending a Session Variable to Another Page

Tags: php, session, variables

I'm looking to take a session variable created during login and send them to another page.

On page one, which is a form, I tested that the variables like this:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    $variable = $_SESSION['steamid'];
    echo  $variable;
    echo $_SESSION['steamid'];
```

and it echoed my variable correctly twice. The problem is that I can't access the variable on the next page that takes the variables from the previous page and uploads them to a database.

This is the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'report.php';
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }
     $value2 = $_SESSION['steamid'];
     $value1 = $_POST['64id'];
     $value3 = $_POST['info'];
     $value4 = $_POST['ev'];
     $value5 = $_POST['grp'];
echo $value2;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO Tool (64id, b64id, info, ev, grp) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', 
     '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";
     mysql_query($sql);
     mysql_close();
?>
```

But the code does not echo $value2 or send it to the database.

Any help?

Full script of Page one is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tool</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>


<?php 
session_start();

require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
$userPermitted = array(
                       //D2TRG
                       76561198058365176, // Del

                       //TFTRG
                       76561198019973842, // Frost
                       76561198044873576, // Gamma
                       76561198061239658, // Walker
                       76561198037237481, // Tyrone
                       76561198059430645, // Walker
                       76561198071750788, // Love
                       76561198053519412, // Artful
                       76561198073355125, // Hazard
                       76561198046958131, // Yunz
                       76561198059682839, // Lulu
                       76561198050610274, // Knitro
                       76561198059179348, // Kelvin
                       76561198069400954, // Kodorin
                       76561198068702942, // Champion
                       76561198059420483); // Dee_Jay


if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
    steamlogin(); //login button
} else {
     $variable = $_SESSION['steamid'];
    $html = '<div id="container">
            <h1>Report a User</h1>
            <form action="run.php" method="post" id="form"/>
            <p>User\'s 64 ID: <input type="text" name="64id"/></br>
            <p>Group:</p><select name="grp">
  <option value="tftrg">TFTRG</option>
  <option value="ttrg">TTRG</option>
  <option value="fmgr">FmGr</option>
  <option value="d2trg">DTRG</option>
  <option value="kgbdan">KGBdan</option>
 </select>
            <p>Infringement:<br><textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="info"></textarea></br>
            <p>Evidence:<br> <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="ev"></textarea></br>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>


';

   if (in_array($_SESSION['steamid'], $userPermitted)){
        include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
        echo $html;
        echo "You are currently logged in as: " . $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>";
        echo '<img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title="" alt="" />'; // Display their avatar!
        echo  $variable;
        logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
          }
    else{
        echo 'user is not permitted to use this tool';
    }
}
?>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: there is no code where you assign anything to `$_SESSION['steamid']`, maybe something wrong in `steamlogin()` ?

Comment: The SteamID session variable is assigned in another script. I know that it has a value because I can echo it in page one.

Comment: Get rid of all the unnecessary code and leave just assigning value to session variable in first page, and showing its value on second page (like in Azrael's answer). If that doesn't work then you might have something wrong in your session settings in php.ini. If works, then you lose your session variable value somewhere in the code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

change

```
$variable = $_SESSION['steamid'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['steamid'] = $variable;
```

Comment: $_SESSION['steamid'] already has a value. I only used $variable to verify that it did.